Kernel of inflation of $H^2$ in Galois cohomology
For a finite set $T$ of primes let $G_T$ denote the Galois group of the maximal extension $K_T$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is unramified outside $T$.
Let $S$ denote a finite set of primes and let $S' = S\cup\{q\}$ be the union of $S$ with a single prime $q\not\in S$.
Clearly $K_S$ is a subfield of $K_{S'}$, and there is a short exact sequence of Galois groups $1\to N\to G_{S'} \to G_S\to 1$.
Question 1: is $N$ isomorphic to $I_q$, the absolute inertia group of $Q$ at the prime $q$?
Question 2: let $M$ be a pure-weight $k$ $G_S$-finite $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module of finite rank with $p\in S$. Assuming $k$ is large enough, is the inflation map $H^2(G_{S'}, M)\to H^2(G_S, M)$ injective?
The inflation restriction exact sequence for $H^2$ gives the kernel of the inflation map as a quotient of $H^1(N, M)^{G_S}$. Now since $N$ acts trivially, $H^1(N, M)$ is $\text{Hom}(N, M)$, however if the answer to Q1 is yes, then $N=I_q$ is an extension of the tame inertia by wild inertia. Wild inertia is pro-$q$, so any homomorphism factors through the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ quotient of the tame inertia.
Let $\tau$ denote its generator, and let $\phi$ denote a lift of the mod $q$ Frobenius to $G_S$. Then $\phi$ acts on $\tau$ via conjugation by raising to the $q$'th power. There are two possible actions of $g\in G_S$ on $f\in\text{Hom}(N, M)$, sending $f(n)$ to $f(g^{-1}ng)$, and acting on $f(n)$ as an element of $M$. I assume the action is given by $(gf)(n) = g(f(g^{-1}ng))$. In this case $\phi$ sends $f$ to $q\cdot \phi f$, so this suggests that $H^1(N, M)^{G_S} = 0$ whenever $k\neq \pm1$, depending on the "orientation".
I imagine I made multiple mistakes here and would appreciate some guidance on what these are.

The answer to question 1 is negative, even in the simplest case. Suppose that $S=\varnothing$ so that $K_S=\Bbb Q$, hence $G_{S}=1$ so $N=G_{S'}$. In this case, there is still a relation between $G_{S'}$ and the inertia, though: $G_{S'}$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$ by the smallest closed normal subgroup containing the inertia subgroup $I_q$.

Geometrically, one can also describe this quotient as $\pi_1(\mathbf{Spec}(\Bbb Z[1/q])$. $I_q$ is a pro-solvable group. In fact, it is an extension of a pro-$q$ group by a finite abelian group of order prime to $q$, as is well-known. But $\pi_1(\mathbf{Spec}(\Bbb Z[1/q])$ is not pro-solvable. It suffices to show that there is a finite non-solvable Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ that is ramified only at a single prime.

For such examples, see https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?start=0&num_ram=1&field_is=nsolv
